# Are there regulatory documents to carry medical kits and defibrillators on-board?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, medical, airworthiness

Are there any regulatory release documents applicable for carrying medical kits and defibrillators on-board a commercial airliner?

For example for:

1. Components, you are required to have an EASA Form 1 or FAA 8130-3 release tag.
2. Standard Parts, you can accept with a CoC (Certificate of Conformity/Conformance).

What are similar standards for emergency/medical equipment?

Comment: I think this depends on what type of operation you are. If you are going part 91, there isn't one. I also don't think there is one for commercial operations less than 10 or 12 passengers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it made me realise I should have clarified my question is for commercial airlines.

Comment: Again ‘commercial’ is a relative term and can apply to the Part 91 ops that Ron Breyer described as well.  You’re probably thinking of scheduled air carrier operations under Part 121.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about scheduled carriers such as BA, Lufthansa, Emirates, etc

Comment: You tagged both [faa-regulations] and [easa-regulations]. None of the 3 airlines you mentioned fly under Part 121 [faa-regulations]. Only BA and Lufthansa fly under [easa-regulations]. Could you clarify what country/region you want to know about?

Comment: Yes because all of these airlines maintain accept components with EASA and FAA release certificates. The question is whether any regulatory body from the two classifies such medical equipment in a category that requires a Form 1/8130-3 or CoC to be eligible for fitment.

Comment: These requirements will likely be found in the company manual, if not elswhere.

Comment: Thanks J Walter, I suppose from a regulatory perspective, there's no roadblock so the control mechanism would be the organisation's procedures!

Answer (score 2):

I can’t comment on ICAO requirements, but for domestic and Flag Operations in the US, §121.801 - §121.805 and §121 Appendix A cover the requirements for emergency medical equipment, including electronic defibrillators, to be onboard scheduled air carrier aircraft and specify training requirements for flight crew members on their use.

Comment: Hi Carlo, indeed the requirement for having these onboard exists but I was wondering about any specific airworthiness or CoC document requirements? Or can such equipment and kits be carried without any such documents?